# Trouble opening file from list

Tags: python, list

I have made a list based off of files in a folder that begin with "MTDR". The user then confirms "y" that it's the file they would like to open, and then it's *supposed to* open that file. The bit I'm struggling with is it instead opens all the files in the folder instead of the [-1] specifically in the list. I've probably got way over-complicated code but any pointers would be appreciated, thanks!

```
for item in dirListing:
    if item.startswith("MTDR"):
        MTDR_names=  [os.path.abspath(path)+"/"+files for files in os.listdir(path)] print(sorted(MTDR_names, reverse=True,)) print('') print('Is '+ MTDR_names[-1]+' the correct revision of the MTDR? (y/n)') MTDR_answer = input() while True:
    if MTDR_answer == 'y':
           MTDR_selector = MTDR_names[-1]
        print(MTDR_selector[-1], reverse=True)
        for i in MTDR_selector:
            os.popen(MTDR_selector,'r')
```

Comment: Would you mind fixing some of the indentation levels? I have some idea of where the print statements go, but I'd rather not make an inaccurate edit

Comment: @C.Nivs I tried to change it a bit, but I'm really new to python and I can't exactly tell where my indentations are wrong atm.

Comment: as long as they are the same as the code you have written, then that's the best place to start